# Maps that go to Interior or exterior of an ellipse.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

The function $w(z)=-(1/z +bz), -1<b<1$ maps $\lvert z \rvert <1$ onto

(1) Interior of the ellipse .

(2) Exterior of the ellipse.

> I got an equation of ellipse but how can I get the interior or exterior?

Comment: Can you show us the equation that you got for the ellipse you got?

Comment: $(u/(1+b))^{2}+(v/(b-1))^{2}=1$

Comment: So all $u$ and $v$ for which the LHS evaluates to less than 1 is the interior, isn't it?

Comment: bot 0 maps to infinity....

Comment: Is infinity in the interior or the exterior of an ellipse...any ellipse?

Comment: Extterior. I ask that is that the only to determine